# How to crop strings using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

Here's the phrase I'd like to convert.

```
Summoner1 joined the lobby.
Summoner2 jonied the lobby.
Summoner3: Top
Summoner4: ADC
```

I wanna pick up these words `Summoner1, Summoner2, Summoner3, Summoner4`.
I suppose I should detect the strings `"joined the lobby"`, and `": "`  using regular expression(regex) but I have no clue how to.

Thank you in advance.

Codes for extra question.
`var list = @"Summoner1 joined the lobby.
Summoner2 jonied the lobby.
Summoner3: Top
Summoner4: ADC";
            var result = string.Join("|", list.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, "( |:).*", string.Empty)));`

Comment: `input.Split(new [] {':',' '}).First()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Regex, you can use the following.

```
"( |:).*"
```

Example,

```
var list= @"Summoner1 joined the lobby.
Summoner2 jonied the lobby.
Summoner3: Top
Summoner4: ADC";


var result = list.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=> Regex.Replace(x,"( |:).*",string.Empty));
```

**Update: Based on Comment**

```
var result = string.Join("|",list.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=> Regex.Replace(x,"( |:).*",string.Empty)));
```

Output

```
Summoner1|Summoner2|Summoner3|Summoner4
```

Comment: thank you for your answer so very much. Would you be so kind as to answer the following question? I want it to be in the same line like Summoner1|Summoner2|Summoner3|Summoner4 to be able to use regex multiple matches.

Comment: you mean the input string would be in mentioned format or result ?

Comment: yeah the latter one. the result.

Comment: @XHSKR I have updated the answer for you, you can use string.Join for the purpose.

Comment: I have updated the question. it says unable to convert from char to string.

Comment: Have updated and clean up the Answer based on your updated OP. Now it became more clear that your input was a long string rather than list of string. The updated answer should work for you now

Comment: Thank you !! Now I can sleep well. dunno what time it is now in your country, but have a good one. I'm not gonna bother you anymore T_T thank you again for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
       string sourc = @"Summoner1 joined the lobby.
Summoner2 jonied the lobby.
Summoner3: Top
Summoner4: ADC";
        Regex reg = new Regex("^[\\s]*(Summoner[\\d])+.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var result = reg.Matches(sourc).ToList().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```